# C# Switch between windows of another process

Tags: c#, windows, process

I have written a C# program that can bring the windows of two other processes (that are already running) to the screen.
This works fine on my computer.

But when I run the program on another computer, I have the problem that the windows do not come to the screen, instead their icons in the taskbar just get highlighted in yellow.

Does anyone know what the problem might be on the PC where this is not working?

To switch between windows of the processes I use the commands

```
ShowWindow 
SetForegroundWindow
```

I have also tried

```
SwitchToThisWindow
```

But same problem.

Comment: No, I am using Windows 10

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow You might want to read the remarks part. There are tight rules when getting something in the foreground is allowed. Mosty its just annoying so prevented by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.
I found the problem:
I have to call

```
AllowSetForegroundWindow
```

first. Than it works.